# daisy chain ethernet connection with other pi's

Tags: networking, ethernet, internet

Is it possible to daisy chain the ethernet connection between pi's

Internet/ethernet in to pi #1 then share this internet connection with pi #2 via usb to ethernet adapter? or otherwise?

Comment: Certainly possible, it's called routing.  What OS do your RPi's have? Do you want to avoid investing in a switch?

Comment: WiFi-accesspoint might be an option as well...

Comment: im on raspbian 9, yeah want try without a switch if possible...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can enable `ip forwarding` on every raspi so all of them work as router. But then you have to setup different networks for every ethernet connection so you can route packets between the networks, e.g.

```
rpiA[eth1:192.168.0.1/24] -> rpiB[eth0:192.168.0.2/24 # eth1:192.168.1.1/24] -> rpiC[eth0:192.168.1.2/24]
```

You can fiddle with the netmask to reduce the size of the different networks.

Better is to use a bridge on every raspi so all of them have the same broadcast domain.

Comment: Maybe useful to show how to configure RPi in bridge mode, and a few words on any limitations that result from operating in that mode?

Comment: @Seamus The question is nearly two years old now and to vague and without any feedback from the OP. I'm not very motivated to invest more effort ... If you like just edit the answer.

Comment: Understood... I voted for yr answer, but didn't notice the age. But not to worry, I won't take my vote away :)  But seriously, it's an odd question. I thought it might be about saving the cost of an E'net switch.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your internet conection is with the WiFi interface
Assuming you're running a good distro for the Pi like Ubuntu 16.04
or Raspbian.

You can install a firewall like [preferred] Shorewall Firewall. 
It uses configuration files that are then compiled and a set
of iptables commands are created and inserted into a bash script 
that runs the firewall with masquerading. This way your internal
LAN network masquerades behind your external WAN WiFi interface.

I have a basic configuration that uses (4) files:
- policy     - the basic policy of the firewall,
- rules      - the rules you create for in/out trafffic,
- interfaces - the external interface [WAN],
- zones      - the zones of the firewall.
See https://shorewall.org/

Here are my configuration files for my firewall/router, a
Pi 3 B:

## rpi3b as the HOMENET firewall and router

### Network hardware Configuration

- eth0 as the external interface. On-board eth interface.
- eth1 as the local 10.0.100.240/28 interface. USB/eth dongle #3.
- eth2 as the local 10.0.200.240/28 interface. USB/eth dongle #4.
- USB layout: [  1  ][  2  ]
            [  3  ][  4  ]

### Operating System

- Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

### Firewall

- Shorewall firewall v5.0.4.

### Firewall configurataion

## /etc/shorewall/policy

#

## SOURCE DEST    POLICY      LOG LIMIT:      CONNLIMIT:

$FW     net     ACCEPT
net     all     DROP        NFLOG

## The FOLLOWING POLICY MUST BE LAST

all     all     REJECT      NFLOG

### #END

## /etc/shorewall/rules

#

## ACTION     SOURCE      DEST        PROTO

Ping(DROP)  net         $FW
DNS(ACCEPT) $FW         net
SSH(ACCEPT) loc         $FW
ACCEPT      $FW         net         icmp

## Remote ssh access from the net to internal system ix

## DNAT       net         fw:10.0.100.241:22  tcp 11701

### #END

## /etc/shorewall/zones

## ZONE   TYPE

#
fw      firewall
net     ipv4
loc     ipv4

### #END

## /etc/shorewall/interfaces

#

## ZONE   INTERFACE       BROADCAST   OPTIONS

net             detect          dhcp,tcpflags,logmartians # external
loc         detect      tcpflags,logmartians # internal 100 subnet
loc         detect      tcpflags,logmartians # internal 200 subnet

### #END

## /etc/shorewall/masq

#

## INTERFACE:DEST     SOURCE      ADDRESS

10.0.100.240/28,10.0.200.240/28

### #END